# FindDistribution and parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

If I generate some data using

`data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 100]`

Then find the distribution using

(1) `FindDistribution[data]`

Mathematica gives me an estimated distribution (correctly guesses a Normal) and values of that distributions parameters.

However, if I then do

(2) `EstimatedDistribution[data, NormalDistribution[a, b]]`

or

(3) `FindDistributionParameters[data, NormalDistribution[a, b]]`

Mathematica gives me different "best fit" parameter estimates. Using defaults, (2) and (3) give the same results, and (1) gives different results.

Looking at the documentation it looks like (2) and (3) might use a different method by default to (1). But I have been unable to get (1) to give the same results as (2) and (3). Is there a simple way (options) to make the results consistent.

A couple of more general questions:

Are there any "rules" as to when one should use (1), versus (2) or (3) to **get parameter values**. Obviously (1) finds a distribution, versus (2) and (3) finding best fit parameters of a specified distribution.

The three functions seem very related, so it seems confusing that by default they did not give the same best fit parameters.

Comment: Weird, I thing this is a **bug**, notice that `FindDistribution[data,PerformanceGoal->"Quality",TargetFunctions-> {NormalDistribution}]` gives the same solution as other methods but not `FindDistribution[data,PerformanceGoal->"Quality",TargetFunctions-> {NormalDistribution, WeibullDistribution}]`.

Comment: As for the question *"when one should use"* each function, I think `FindDistribution` makes most sense only when you are exploring different hypotheses on what could be the underlying distribution, but not as the means to extract parameters of known distributions. However, given that there is a bug in that function, I would say it does not make sense to use `FindDistribution` at all until the scope of the bug is understood or fixed.

Comment: @rhermans: Let us increase the sample  size. Then `RandomSeeding[{1, 2, 3, 4}]; data = 
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 200];FindDistribution[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 TargetFunctions -> {NormalDistribution, WeibullDistribution}]` results in `NormalDistribution[5.36896, 3.09436]` , whehereas `FindDistributionParameters[data, NormalDistribution[a, b]]` performs `{a -> 5.36618, b -> 3.00919}`. It should be noticed that `FindDistribution` is sensitive to a sample size. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need. PS.  A very similar result with with the size =150.

Comment: @user64494 Well, no surprise that increasing the number of points gives solutions that are closer. Still remains that the output changes depending on options that **should NOT** make any difference, like the number of alternative `TargetFunctions`. Circumventing a bug by tweaking options obviously doesn't give information about that bug, and does not constitute an answer to the question at hand, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Two quotes from the documentation shed light on it:

> By default, `FindDistributionParameters` uses maximum likelihood to estimate distribution parameters for a fixed distribution.
> `FindDistribution` uses a full Bayesian approach by combining the Bayesian information criterion with priors
> over distributions to select both the best distribution and the best parameters for it.

> The option `TargetFunctions` can be used if you want to find roughly the same parameters as `FindDistributionParameters`

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 100];
FindDistribution[data, TargetFunctions -> {NormalDistribution}]
```

> `NormalDistribution[5.26867, 2.8738]`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I elaborated more in a comment to the question. I do appreciate the effort and goodwill, but that is something else.

Comment: The question is "But I have been unable to get (1) to give the same results as (2) and (3). Is there a simple way (options) to make the results consistent". I answered it. It is your personal opinion that you find something "this" to be a bug.

Comment: @rhermans You say that the answer should not depend on the `TargetFunctions` specified, but this answer actually explains that that's an invalid assumption. In a Bayesian setting, the results depend on your priors and setting different `TargetFunctions` changes the priors and hence the result.

Comment: This answer is correct and the only thing missing is the admonition:  "Don't use `FindDistribution` until the documentation clearly explains exactly what "uses a Bayesian information criterion together with priors" means.  There's nothing wrong with using a Bayesian approach (and it's probably what one should be using) but without knowing what's under the hood, one shouldn't use it at all.  `EstimatedDistribution` and `FindDistributionParameters` are not completely innocent either:  Neither produce estimates of precision.  Estimates should always be paired with an estimate of precision.

Comment: The estimated parameters for the `NormalDistribution`  should be calculated **"given that the distribution is `NormalDistribution`"**. It doesn't make sense that the *"prior probability"* of the *"underlying probability been a `WeibullDistribution`"* changes the estimated parameter value for the `NormalDistribution`.

Comment: The answer should say that `FindDistribution` should not be used for the task at hand, the documentation is not clear enough, as pointed out by @JimB. I go further, I say the answer given by  `FindDistribution` is incorrect if it depends on the options on `TargetFunctions`.

Comment: @rhermans There are apparently priors for the target functions AND the parameters.  A Bayesian would not use Bayesian methods for choosing the target functions and then use maximum likelihood for estimating the parameters.  (Maybe you had the same English professors that I had where they would walk out of the room when someone mentioned Bayes.)  Having the details in the documentation would clear all of this up.

Comment: @JimB I don't consider myself a *Frequentist*.  Do you say that my assertion is incorrect? That is, Am I wrong when I say *The estimated parameters for the `NormalDistribution` should be calculated "given that the distribution is `NormalDistribution`"* ?.

Comment: @user64494, also in the question *"when one should use (1), versus (2) or (3) to get parameter values."*. I think we should be moving this discussion to a chat.

Comment: The documentation says, *"Bayesian approach by combining the Bayesian information criterion with priors over distributions to select both the best distribution and the best parameters for it."* I read that as  *"best distribution"* and *"best parameters"* are independent. If it said *"best joined distribution and parameters"*, I would agree that `FindDistribution` gives a correct result, but such result is NOT the best answer for the OP.

Comment: @rhermans Yes, I think your assertion is incorrect because one of the sources of variation is the selection of the target distribution.  One's posterior belief is tempered by all of the priors (which includes the priors on the target distributions and the parameters).  On a different topic:  why would one want *Mathematica* (or anyone else) set priors not knowing your subject matter or your prior beliefs settings the priors AND not wanting to tell you what those priors are.  If one was attempting to defend an analysis in court, they'd be in big trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136341/discussion-between-rhermans-and-jimb).